# Safari quits just after launch with 'Err: connect ECONNREFUSED error' on iOS when using Appium

Tags: ios, ruby, rspec, capybara, appium

I'm new to mobile testing and I wanted to try Appium with Capybara. I've already configured Appium to run and open Safari but just after opening it goes to 0.0.0.0 page, closes and throws an error:

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: Could not navigate to webview! Err: connect
>   ECONNREFUSED ::1:27753

I'm using:

Appium: 1.7.2

Xcode: 9.3

That's my spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'appium_capybara'

Capybara.run_server = false
desired_caps_ios = {
  deviceName:      "iPhone Simulator",
  browserName:     'Safari',
  platformName:    "iOS",
  platformVersion: "11.3",
  automationName:  'XCUITest'
}

url = "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"

Capybara.register_driver(:appium) do |app|
    appium_lib_options = { 
      server_url:           url 
    }   
    all_options = { 
      appium_lib:  appium_lib_options,
      caps:        desired_caps_ios
    }   
    Appium::Capybara::Driver.new app, all_options
end

Capybara.default_driver = :appium

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end
```

And my test is just:

```
it 'test' do
  visit 'https://google.com'
end
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figure it out! Just the newest version of iOS(11.3) is not yet supported by Appium. I had to download SDKs for iOS 11.2.